# get id of simple product of any configurable product on cart.phtml magento

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product

I am working with configurable product, I want simple product id of configurable product on cart.phtml, I am using this code

```
 <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
$_product = $_item->getProduct();
echo $_product->getId();
 <?php endforeach ?>
```

but it always gives main product id, but I need its simple product id , any one help please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In quote item table magento have sku and  product id. For Configurable product's cart , 'sku' is simple product sku and product id  is configurable product 'id'.
SO, you need to load product by sku

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
 $_Configproduct = $_item->getProduct();
 $simpleProduct=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku());
echo $simpleProduct->getId();
<?php endforeach ?
```

Comment: This wouldn't work.  $_item in your example is still the configurable product and would end up loading the configurable product id once more.

Comment: ok,let checks   .

Comment: try echo  $_item->getSku() , check what is return??

Comment: I forgot hat it stores the simple SKU for both configurable & simple in quote table.  I was wrong, it would load the correct simple product ID.

Answer (score 5):

Try this : **$_item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')->getProduct()->getId()**

**Source :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027524/get-simple-product-from-configurable-in-cart

After taking a look at how Magento renders the items in your cart on the checkout/cart page, I was able to find this in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer/Configurable.php`

```
/**
 * Get item configurable child product
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
 */
public function getChildProduct()
{
    if ($option = $this->getItem()->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
        return $option->getProduct();
    }
    return $this->getProduct();
}
```

So, applying it to the snippet in the question, it would be

```
foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    if ($option = $item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
        $productId = $option->getProduct()->getId();
    }
    $productIds[] = $productId;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, `$this->getItems()` actually calls:

```
$this->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Which only returns products you actually see on the cart page (configurable, stand-alone simple, bundle, etc).

You need the simple.  So here we go (This code I tested in checkout/cart/item/default.phtml).

```
if ($_item->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE)
{
      //Return first item of the array, in the case of 'configurable', it will be a one item array.
      $_simpleItem = reset($_item->getChildren());

      //print out simple id
      echo $_simpleItem->getProductId();
}
```

Comment: Or you could do `$_item->getChildrenIds()` to get all IDs of the associated simple products.

Comment: You could, but I think my method is more powerful for no extra work.  What are you going to do with that product ID?  Load the full product to get information off of it?  You don't need to as now you can "$_simpleItem->getProduct()" and you have the full product ready to go.  But yes, you are correct; that method would work as well depending on what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Magento itself provides the solution of getting the simple product object from configurable in the following <del>file</del> class:

**`Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Configurable`**

function name is **`getChildProduct()`** which returns the simple product object from configurable one.

```
public function getChildProduct()
{
    if ($option = $this->getItem()->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
        return $option->getProduct();
    }
    return $this->getProduct();
}
```